# Как наложить фильтр на ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Я хочу сделать фильтр на чёрно-белое изображение, это мне нужно для разных тем в приложении. Как я понимаю для этого надо использовать

```
ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_header);
header.setColorFilter(R.color.my_color);
```

Я создал отдельный проект для тестирования и вот что получилось:

[image: Чёрно-белое изображение]

Но если я нажимаю на любую кнопку, кроме "убрать фильтр" (он ставит цвет android.R.color.transparent), получается вот такая фигня:

[image: Странный фильтр]

Почему он делает всё фиолетовым? По логике всё должно работать. Приведу код применения цвета полностью:

```
...

// Покрасить в красный
public void setRedColor(View v) {
ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);
header.setColorFilter(R.color.red);
}

// Покрасить в синий
public void setBlueColor(View v) {
ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);
header.setColorFilter(R.color.blue);
}

// Покрасить в зелёный
public void setGreenColor(View v) {
ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);
header.setColorFilter(R.color.green);
}

// Убрать краску
public void setNullColor(View v) {
ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);
header.setColorFilter(android.R.color.transparent);
}
```

Разметка:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/header"/>

    <Button
        android:onClick="setRedColor"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Красный"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:onClick="setBlueColor"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Синий"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:onClick="setGreenColor"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Зелёный"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:onClick="setNullColor"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Убрать фильтр"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: А что из себя представляют R.color.my_color, R.color.red и т.д.?

Comment: @Serodv это цвета, например `#F44336`

Comment: Попробуйте побольше кода выложить, может в логике искать надобно. Тут как бы особых проблем нет.

Comment: @Serodv а куда ещё больше? Это всё, больше кода я не писал

Comment: тогда Layout давайте

Comment: @Serodv добавил в вопрос

Comment: Да и тут вроде всё норм...

Comment: @Serodv и в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Не могу сказать. Подвох может быть во всём. Поменяйте картинку, поиграйтесь с цветами, стилями... вариантов много

Comment: Попробуйте header.setColorFilter(android.R.color.transparent, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);

Comment: @McDaggen тогда красный превращается в фиолетовый и красит всю картину

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался с проблемой, надо было сделать так:

```
header.setColorFilter(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.red), PorterDuff.Mode.ADD);
```

Answer (score 2):

Поменяйте каждый `setColorFilter` на `setColorFilter(this.getResources().getColor(R.color. ... ))`

но `getColor()`  не рекомендован  после API 23, но можно воспользоваться `v4 support` либо другим `getColor()` для API>=23

Comment: Такой способ полностью красит изображение, а мне надо _наложить фильтр_